# Locked myself out of remote server

Tags: server, ssh, authentication, remote-access

Before I left, I've set up an old computer with Lubuntu 14.04 32-bit. While trying to set up rtorrent, I did something to lock myself out while following [this tutorial](http://www.torrent-invites.com/showthread.php?t=272228).

Normally my computer has one user only, and I login through SSH. However, I added a new user while doing this just like it said and now I can't login as the new user or myself.  I do still have a living FTP connection.

How can I restore access to my server?

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but this site is not meant for urgent situations. It's a Q&A website for sharing knowledge. If you need urgent help, please use the AskUbuntu [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). I've edited your question accordingly. See also [How do we deal with “urgent!” questions?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5849/88802).

Answer (score 1):

Nope, if you've disabled remote root access and you can't login with your new account, you need physical access to go through the [normal recovery process](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/449).

You could try talking somebody through that but otherwise, it's a trip home.